# Improvements to a suggested edit should be saved even if the suggested edit was approved

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, improve-edit

When you try to improve a suggested edit, and the edit gets approved while before you hit "Save Edits", the improved can no longer be saved:

[image: Errors]

The problem here is that Jesse didn't really "already edit" the post, it is just the suggested edit that was [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1581405). There is nothing new, my edit already started with that version that now supposedly conflicts. The edit conflict that is assumed by the system doesn't actually exist.

If I had hit "Save Edits" a little earlier before approval of the suggestion, my changes would have been saved. Now I'll only get my improvements saved if I mess around with new tabs and copy&paste.

If I try to improve an edit I should be able to save it, even if the underlying suggested edit got approved. Since I have the reputation to submit the edit as a standalone edit, it should also work on top of an approved edit suggestion.

Comment: Damn Jesse and his editing!